# Angle of rotation of $w = \frac{1}{z}$ at the points $1$ and $i$

Tags: complex-analysis

What angle of rotation is produced by the transformation $w=\frac{1}{z}$ at the point

(a) $z_{0} = 1$

(b) $z_{0} = i$

I'm not sure what to do. At first I though about representing $w=\frac{1}{z}$ in polar coordinates and then plugging in the point in question, but I know this is wrong...

I also know I am supposed to do something with differentiation...do I take $zf'(z)$ or something like that and then plug in i and compare the change in angle from the point in question? I am quite confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here , $f(z)=\frac{1}{z}$. $f'(z)=-\frac{1}{z^2}$.

Angle of rotation at the point $z_0=1$ is $\arg f'(1)=\arg(-1)=\pi$.

Angle of rotation at the point $z_0=i$ is $\arg f'(i)=\arg(1)=0$.